# Is it possible to quickly invite people to join a group rather than just adding them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I recently created a Facebook group.  I'd like to invite a bunch of people to join the group instead of adding them without their permission.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible Facebook mail which will be received as notification so that multiple friends can join.

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

Just send them a Facebook mail with the link to the group and an explanation of why you think they might like to join the group.

Comment: Updated the question to add the caveat "quickly".  I want to just check a bunch of people off on a list and then push a button, rather than having to craft a message for each invitee individually.  Sending a big group message seems kind of spammy.

Comment: how is inviting multiple people to join a group by whatever method you are thinking of less spammy than sending a message to multiple people, both groups will still receive the notifications / mails (depending on their notification settings anyway)

Comment: Because it would go into Notifications rather than Messages.

Comment: Also there's the possibility that a message will get placed into the Other box and people won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to add people in Facebook group with script instead of adding them one by one manually. This method bypasses limit of 1000 members so now you can add 1000 plus members in your Facebook group.
https://hackingtryx.blogspot.com/2015/05/script-to-add-all-friends-in-group.html

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, since it's your own blog your linking to, you need to state so explicitly in order to avoid having your post deleted as spam. See the [Help Center](/help/promotion) for more information.